# AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '******-*****-*****-*****-*********'

Tags: django, authentication, azure-active-directory, office365, o365-flow

I am trying to allow o365 login in my Django project using "Django Microsoft Authentication Backend (https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)" but I keep getting this error when i try to log in with my microsoft credentials.

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '******-*****-*****-*****-*********'.
```

I have checked the links i added to my django project and in AAD but cannot figure out the problem

PS: i am doing testing on my local host i.e. localhost:8000

my redirect URI in AAD is :

**http://localhost:8000/microsoft/auth-callback/**

and i have set DEBUG = TRUE

In addition, i have chosen allow accounts in any organizational directory (multi-tenant) login option

Comment: Is it convenient to provide your code configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a general solution to the problem of **not match**:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request URL, you will find redirect_uri, copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

For the redirect URL, it should start with `https`, if you need to start with http, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the authorization request and find what is the actual value of the *redirect_uri* parameter being sent.