# Azure PHP web app ad integration The reply URL specified in the request does not match

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I deploy my web app to azure and my app url which is "https://test.azurewebsites.net", and
I also created "new registerations" from "app registration" in "azure active directory". Inside app registration I add "REDIRECT_URL" which is also same url "https://test.azurewebsites.net". After that, I go to my azure web app and inside authentication/authorization part. I made App Service Authentication on. I selected express security and selected existing AD app.

After that, when I go to "https://test.azurewebsites.net", it ask my azure username and password. I wrote them but It returns me an error. I know there are same problems in stackoverflow but I tried every of them but didn't work.

`"AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: "`

`redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%test.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&`

Answer (score 2):

I have answered similar questions before, please see:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776175/aadsts50011-the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-does-not-match-the-reply-url/63792388#63792388).

There is a general solution to the problem of **not match**:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request URL, you will find redirect_uri, copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

For the redirect URL, it should start with `https`, if you need to start with http, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.

Comment: yes inside that url the redirect url is this "redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback"

Comment: ok so I need to clear that redirecty url like "https://test.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback". and I should paste it inside the azure ad redirect url?

Comment: @newUser  Yes!  you need.

Comment: You must make sure that the reply url you configure in the code is exactly the same as the reply url you set in Azure ad, otherwise, it will report an error.

Comment: yes it will give me an error. "HTTP Error 500.74 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 but how can I get username when I logged in.

Comment: I think from this url ""https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me""

Comment: But how can I redirect from https://test.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback. to https://test.azurewebsites.net/ because before azure ad I could go to my webpage in this url "https://test.azurewebsites.net/". but now I cant.