# Active directory login not working with error "The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application"

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have configure the active directory login as per document but its always give me error "The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application"

My configuration and setting as below.

```
appsettings.json
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "https://localhost:44300/",
    "ClientId": "94652b2b-ac2d-470c-b8a8-8ce7c7691aca",
    "TenantId": "0ef71077-dc27-4e28-a028-a10542145dfc",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
```

Startup.cs

ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddRazorPages()
                 .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();


            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(option =>
            {
                option.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                option.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddAzureAD(option => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", option));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, option =>
            {
                option.Authority = option.Authority + "/V2.0/";
                option.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateActor = false;
            });
            services.AddMvc(option =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                option.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

Its always ask me for login but after login i got below error message
Sorry, but we’re having trouble with signing you in.

AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '94652b2b-ac2d-470c-b8a8-8ce7c7691aca

Below is my active directory login configuration
Redirect URIs : https://localhost:44300/
Access tokens = checked
ID tokens = checked
Supported account type: Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered similar questions before, please see:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776175/aadsts50011-the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-does-not-match-the-reply-url/63792388#63792388).

There is a general solution to the problem of not match:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request URL, you will find redirect_uri, copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.
[image]

For the redirect URL, it should start with `https`, if you need to start with http, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.