# AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application. How to specify redirect URI?

Tags: python, azure, flask, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following this instruction: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp Afterwards, I get the following error:

AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application

The code gives me the result:

```
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2021 12:09:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2021 12:09:14] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

How to specify the redirect URI correctly, so that I could log in? I've currently tried https://127.0.0.1:5000/ and https://localhost:5000/

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:5000`? Are you sure you have HTTPS supported and setup locally? Based on the log it looks like it's HTTP, not HTTPS.

Comment: Azure won't let me use http instead of https. What can I do about it?(

Comment: With localhost it should be allowed

Comment: 127 is set automatically. Where should I change it?

Comment: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit) // I haven't set it anywhere

Comment: Fixed it with
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='localhost')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like your error message says, you must make sure that the redirect uri you configured in the code is exactly the same as the redirect uri you configured in the Azure portal.

[image]

There is a [general solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776175/aadsts50011-the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-does-not-match-the-reply-url/63792388#63792388) to the problem of **not match**:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request URL, you will find redirect_uri, copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

Comment: The redirect URI is http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2FgetAToken
I've figured that this is  http://127.0.0.1:5000/getAToken
However, Azure won't let me use http instead of https. So the error stays :(

Comment: @AnnaDenisova  You cannot use `127.0.0.1`. It cannot be used with `http`. You should use `localhost` instead. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776175/aadsts50011-the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-does-not-match-the-reply-url/63792388#63792388) I provided has instructions: If you need to start with http, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.

Comment: @AnnaDenisova  Don't worry, `http://localhost` and `http://127.0.0.1` run the same in the browser.

Comment: Was stuck on this for awhile and found that I was in need of adding signin-microsoft to the end of my redirect URI e.g.`https://localhost:{yourport#}/signin-microsoft` for a sign-in with Microsoft setup. Thank you for the tip on looking at the login request url.