# Azure AD Login with groups get error AADSTS50011

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have an azure website that use ADD login, it works fine locally.
I have Authentication Web URIs setting

```
https://hcmerp-admin-dev-slot.azurewebsites.net/
https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc
https://hcmerp-admin-dev-slot.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc
```

I get this error when I trying to login

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the 
application: 'e6ac92bc-9a0d-4dd7-ba6f-41428cf0b04f'.
```

The URL on the error page is

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/27b36724-47e7-4a5d-a318-e26c4968d3c2/oauth2/authorize? 
client_id=e6ac92bc-9a0d-4dd7-ba6f-41428cf0b04f&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhcmerp-admin-dev- 
slot.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-oidc + more
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776175/aadsts50011-the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-does-not-match-the-reply-url/63792388#63792388

Comment: Hi, @Benzhi Pan Does this help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://seankilleen.com/2020/06/solved-net-core-azure-ad-in-docker-container-incorrectly-uses-an-non-https-redirect-uri/
The problem is the .Net core code running in the container. This is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The URL says it is using the following redirect URI parameter: `http%3A%2F%2Fhcmerp-admin-dev-  slot.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-oidc`.
Note at the start it says "http", not "https".

Reply URLs check scheme as well.
For some reason your app is redirecting to HTTP and not using HTTPS for the redirect URI parameter.

Comment: Azure redirect URL MUST be https other than localhost http://hcmerp-admin-dev-slot.azurewebsites.net/ will be redirect to https://hcmerp-admin-dev-slot.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Yes, which is why you need to fix it in your app side. You shouldn't use unsecured connections to transfer authorization codes/tokens any way (outside localhost at least).

Comment: How can I do it exactly? The ADD validation URL I am using is https://login.microsoftonline.com/. It is Azure return the redirect URL according to my App registration setup and My setup uses HTTPS

Comment: How have you configured Azure AD authentication? Do you enforce HTTPS?

Comment: Azure redirect URL MUST be https other than localhost

Comment: Yes it does. But your app is sending the user to auth with HTTP in the redirect_uri parameter. So there must be a configuration error in the application, not in Azure AD app registration configuration.

Comment: you can try it, https://hcmerp-admin-dev-slot.azurewebsites.net/ is a HTTPS, then I call ADD auth with the site which is HTTPS